# Can i see the review queue on the mobile app?

Tags: support

When I'm not at home, I sometimes browse SE through the mobile SE application, but I can't seem to find the review queue on it. Is it impossible to review posts through the mobile SE application?

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported on the mobile app. You could probably do it through the mobile browser, though.

Comment: This is an open feature request at [meta.se]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215841/224428. Your best bet is to open up a mobile browser, switch to desktop mode, and review from there.